# SQL server Srevive(MSSQLSERVER) not start

Tags: sql-server, windows-services

i want to  SQL server 2008 Enterprise Edition on my Dell N5110  Laptop With windows 7 Ultimate SP1 64- bit edition.
when i click "setup" in installation  DVD below Error appear:
[image]

anyway i click Continue and install SQL server
when setup finish installation program show following window
[image]
i click next and window close
when i go to SQL Server Configuration Manager,MSSQLSERVER service not runing
when i try to run this service windows cant do this
[image]
also i try to run sql server service from services widow(service.msc)
but error code 17058 appear.
[image]

how can i solve problem ??
i install sql server 2008 on windows xp 32 bit  computer with this installation media.there are no problem

**---Update----**

i download sql server 2008 SP1 From Microsft.
when i attempt to install SP1 Windows Show me following  error:

[image]

Comment: Does the event log (as indicated in the last error message) give additional info?

Comment: You should Google "install SQL server 2008 Enterprise on Windows 7 64 bit". I see several things that may help. One of them is that you need SP1

Comment: @JanDoggen:where is event log? i go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL and cant find LOG folder

Comment: Start - Run - Eventvwr

Comment: @JanDoggen: can i install SP1 when SQL server itself is not install correctly???

Comment: Dunno. BTW there is also 2008 R2, I don't know if that is a separate SQL Server or just an upgrade to 2008. You'd have to look that up.

Comment: SP1 setup also have error

Comment: i think my windows 7 DotNetFramework  v2.0 have problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the SQL-service is not running and resolved by reinstalling the program!